# Java read data structure from bytes array

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have read some datas into a `readbuf` array from serial port. the buffer contains data structure like below:

```
bytes[] readbuf = new byte[2048];
size = mInputStream.read(readbuf);

transfer_data_des 
{
  for(n;n<lenght;j++)
  {
      U16 xxx_index;
      U32 xxxdataLength;
      for(m;m<xxxdataLength;m++)
      {
        U8 data; //contain hex data
      }
  }
}
```

The structure contains an int `index`, indicate what kind of data, and data is a char arrays. the buffer like below,

```
[int][[length]][char arrays] | [index][length][data] | [index][length][data]|[...]
```

how could I parse it to correct data from the bytes buffer? I am not very specialist in java, please give me some help,  I would highly think you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by correct data?

Comment: Have you tried using DataInputStream? Do you know what endianness is being used? If you've tried something, please give details.

Comment: The data contains an int `index`, indicate what kind of data, and data is a char arrays. [int][char arrays][index][data][index][data][...]